# Mysql запрос для взаимозаменяемого фильтра в интернет магазине

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eav

Задача заключается в том, что бы при выборе определённых значений в фильтре отсекать ненужные значения (те значения которых нет при в полученном списке товаров).

Например есть категория розетки к категории создаётся фильтр с атрибутами производитель, тип изделия, серия и при выборе к примеру определённых производителей и типа изделия необходимо оставить только тот тип изделия и серии которые совпадают с выбранными параметрами в фильтре.

есть 4 таблицы

*свойства товаров*

```
mysql> DESCRIBE attr_value;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(9)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_attr  | int(5)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_goods | int(9)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value_id | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*значения атрибутов*

```
mysql> DESCRIBE attr;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value     | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type_arrt | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*значения свойств*

```
mysql> DESCRIBE attr_value_id;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(9)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*привязка товаров к определённой категории*

```
mysql> DESCRIBE grup_goods;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_goods | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_grup  | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Собираю фильтр без выбранных значений:

```sql
SELECT a_v.id_attr, a_v_id.value AS value, a_v.value_id AS value_id, COUNT(a_v.value_id) AS count_value
FROM attr_value a_v
LEFT JOIN grup_goods g_gr ON a_v.id_goods = g_gr.id_goods
LEFT JOIN attr_value_id a_v_id ON a_v_id.id = a_v.value_id 
WHERE a_v.id_attr IN(".$id_attr_list_query.")
AND
g_gr.id_grup = ".$this_razdel->id."
GROUP BY a_v.value_id
```

Применяю фильтр для выбора товара

```sql
SELECT a_v.id_goods AS g_id, g.title AS title, COUNT( DISTINCT a_v.id_attr ) AS cnt
FROM attr_value a_v 
LEFT JOIN grup_goods gr_g ON a_v.id_goods = gr_g.id_goods 
LEFT JOIN goods g ON g.id = a_v.id_goods 
WHERE (
a_v.id_attr = 4 AND (a_v.value_id =273)
) 
OR 
(a_v.id_attr = 24 AND (a_v.value_id =2174 OR a_v.value_id = 74174)
) 
AND gr_g.id_grup = 753 
GROUP BY a_v.id_goods 
HAVING cnt =2
```

Есть идея вытащить все id товаров и засунуть их в запрос через WHERE_IN но при количестве товаров например 10к штук думаю такой запрос будет тормозить...

Кто сталкивался? Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если переписать (сгенерить) ваш фильтр так:

```sql
SELECT g.id AS g_id, g.title AS title
FROM grup_goods gr_g
  JOIN goods g on gr_g.id_goods = g.id 
  JOIN attr_value a_v4 ON a_v4.id_goods = gr_g.id_goods and a_v4.id_attr = 4
  JOIN attr_value a_v24 ON a_v24.id_goods = gr_g.id_goods and a_v24.id_attr = 24
WHERE gr_g.id_grup = 753
  and a_v4.value_id = 273
  and a_v24.value_id in (2174, 74174)
```

, то не будет агрегаций, запрос будет проще, будут использоваться индексы. И уже такой запрос можно модифицировать, чтобы получить список используемых значений свойств:

```sql
SELECT a_v.id_attr, a_v_id.value, a_v.value_id AS value_id, 
  count(a_v.value_id) count_value
FROM grup_goods gr_g
  JOIN attr_value a_v4 ON a_v4.id_goods = gr_g.id_goods and a_v4.id_attr = 4
  JOIN attr_value a_v24 ON a_v24.id_goods = gr_g.id_goods and a_v24.id_attr = 24
  JOIN attr_value a_v ON a_v.id_goods = gr_g.goods_id
  JOIN attr_value_id a_v_id ON a_v.value_id = a_v_id.id 
WHERE gr_g.id_grup = 753
  and a_v4.value_id = 273
  and a_v24.value_id in (2174, 74174)
GROUP BY a_v.id_attr, a_v_id.value, a_v.value_id
```