# MySql запрос фильтра по товарам, исключить лишние значения

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

id --- cat_id ---   product_id ---  property_id --- value_id

1 ---   207060 ------   1 ---------------   1 ---------------   1
2 ---   207060 ------   1 ---------------   2 ---------------   2
3 ---   207060 ------   1 ---------------   3 ---------------   3
4 ---   207060 ------   1 ---------------   4 ---------------   4
5 ---   207060 ------   1 ---------------   5 ---------------   5

Нужно фильтровать товары по данной таблице

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM products p
JOIN product_p_v pv ON (p.id = pv.product_id)
WHERE p.cat_id = '4002'
  AND ((pv.property_id = '4'
        AND (pv.value_id = 100
             OR pv.value_id = 384285))
       OR (pv.property_id = '75'
           AND (pv.value_id = 793))
       OR (pv.property_id = '119'
           AND (pv.value_id = 60222)))
```

Он работает не совсем правильно, т.к. отображает лишние значения

В идеале нужно чтобы было вот так:

```
 AND (pv.property_id = '4' AND (pv.value_id = 100 or pv.value_id = 384285)) AND (pv.property_id = '75' AND (pv.value_id = 793))
```

Т.е. заменить OR на AND, но так не будет работать т.к. получается что "property_id = '4' AND property_id = '75'"

Просмотрел похожие вопросы, но так и не нашел ответа.

Какие есть варианты решения?

Проблема в том, что value_id (id значения свойств) не уникальный, например имя свойства "Желтый" имеет один id, но может принадлежать к разным id названия свойств, поэтому такой вариант не подходит:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
  FROM product AS p
  JOIN product_option AS o
    ON p.id = o.product_id AND o.option_id in(1, 14, 25)
 GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING count(1)=3
```

Может сможет кто подсказать как адаптировать этот вариант под мой случай? Т.е. под два IN, для property_id и value_id.

---

Спасибо за ответы, решения:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
  JOIN product_p_v pv4 ON p.id = pv4.product_id and pv4.property_id = 4
  JOIN product_p_v pv75 ON p.id = pv75.product_id and pv75.property_id = 75
  JOIN product_p_v pv119 ON p.id = pv119.product_id and pv119.property_id = 119
WHERE p.cat_id = 4002
  AND (pv4.value_id in (100,384285))
  AND (pv75.value_id = 793)
  AND (pv119.value_id = 60222)
```

---

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
JOIN product_p_v pv ON (p.id = pv.product_id)
WHERE p.cat_id = '4002'
  AND (pv.property_id, pv.value_id)
  IN ((4,100),(4,384285),
      (75,793),
      (119, 60222))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pv.property_id) = 3
```

Первый вариант работает быстрее

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу составить запрос MySQL для фильтра по товарам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: @Mike вот ни разу не дубликат. Автор же явно пишет, что тот вариант не подходит.

Comment: @Alex из вашего описания совершенно непонятно чего вы пытаетесь добиться. Пожалуйста, опишите вашу проблему, а не попытки ее решения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вот теперь не дубликат. на момент, когда я нажимал закрыть в вопросе не было второй части. Хотя все равно дубликат, правда подобного вопроса с другим ответом ...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вернее нет, даже изначально указанный дупликат. Посмотрите на второй ответ по тому ответу. Он идентичен тому, который ТС принял по данному вопросу (только чуть чуть усложнить условия)

Comment: @Mike, да согласен, ответы очень похожи, но ответ с решением по моему вопросу всё таки более развернут

Comment: @Alex Ну да, более подогнан под вашу конкретную ситуацию. Его суть от этого же не поменялась. Если у вас будет 4 группы условий и/или таблицы по другому называться, то ответ опять же будет отличатся. А в итоге получаем десятки подобных ответов, выражающих одну идею, обилие которых только усложняют поиск. P.S. у вас что то с индексами на product_p_v не так, видимо нет индекса `(property_id, value_id)` раз первый вариант быстрее оказался

Comment: Дубликаты есть (искать по EAV можно), да: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264319/), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/147160/), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454680/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
  JOIN product_p_v pv4 ON p.id = pv4.product_id and pv4.property_id = 4
  JOIN product_p_v pv75 ON p.id = pv75.product_id and pv75.property_id = 75
  JOIN product_p_v pv119 ON p.id = pv119.product_id and pv119.property_id = 119
WHERE p.cat_id = 4002
  AND (pv4.value_id in (100,384285))
  AND (pv75.value_id = 793)
  AND (pv119.value_id = 60222)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
JOIN product_p_v pv ON (p.id = pv.product_id)
WHERE p.cat_id = '4002'
  AND (pv.property_id, pv.value_id)
  IN ((4,100),(4,384285),
      (75,793),
      (119, 60222))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pv.property_id) = 3
```

Comment: Кроме всего прочего в таком варианте нельзя фильтровать по интервалам (>,<, between), по like...

Comment: @YuraIvanov Если бы автор поставил условие интервального и шаблонного выбора, то предлагаемый шаблон был бы другим, на базе HAVING (SUM(...)).

Comment: Это все к тому, что запрос не универсальный. В любом случае запрос надо генерить и в зависимости от условий в фильтре генерация не должна зависеть, имхо.

Comment: *В любом случае запрос надо генерить* А для неопределённых условий не бывает универсальных запросов. Кстати, не в любом случае - если создать (временную) таблицу условий отбора, то можно обойтись и статическим запросом.

Comment: Смотрите запрос выше, он достаточно универсальный для стандартных условий (=, in, >, <, between, like, rlike). Временная таблица - это еще один уровень абстракции? too complicated...

Comment: @YuraIvanov *запрос выше, он достаточно универсальный* Угу... вот только на любой чих его править надо. А если четыре пропертя? А если в рамках одного пропертя не менее двух разных значений из трёх возможных? Да, как шаблон он достаточно универсален, но вот как запрос - совершенно таки нет.

Comment: Его не надо править. Его нужно собирать. Хоть сто пропертей, хоть 2. Я не настаивал на том, что запрос будет одним, я имел в виду, что структура запроса будет одинаковой для любых вменяемых условий поиска. Все верно, это шаблон. Про "не менее двух возможных" не понял. Значение у свойства для каждого товара одно. Если вы про множественные значения, то речь в классическом eav речи о них не ведется, там другие причуды, начиная от способа хранения таких значений. btw, что можете сказать о скорости вашего запроса? Могу ошибаться, план не смотрел, но по виду индексы не сильно эффективно используются

Comment: @YuraIvanov *Значение у свойства для каждого товара одно* С чего бы? Товар - ботинки, свойство - размер. `product_id` - идентификатор группы, а пара `property_id,value_id` - это атрибуты экземпляра. *что можете сказать о скорости вашего запроса?* На большом массиве данных при наличии необходимых индексов - не знаю, предсказать не берусь. *Его не надо править. Его нужно собирать.* А мой можно сделать статическим с параметрами.

Comment: Размер - это не свойство товара. Размер - это свойство характеристики товара. В общем случае разные характеристики одного товара имеют разные цены, наличие, сертификаты и проч. С некоторой точки зрения - это разные товары (как сущность). И кому могут понадобиться сразу и 35 и 45 размер одних и тех же ботинок притом одновременно я не знаю, по-моему никому. `IN ((4,100),(4,384285),(75,793),(119, 60222))` вы собрались превратить в `IN (?)`. Или вы про какой-то другой запрос?

Comment: @YuraIvanov *кому могут понадобиться сразу и 35 и 45 размер одних и тех же ботинок притом одновременно я не знаю, по-моему никому* Ну, к примеру, я на wildberries всегда заказываю 2, а то и 3, соседних размера обуви - уж очень у них там сантиметры разные... и после примерки беру один, подходящий.

Comment: На wildberries прекрасный фильтр. но он не позволяет выбрать обувь для которой есть одновременно несколько размеров, указанных пользователем. Он выбирает обувь, которая имеет хотя бы один из размеров, указанных пользователем, обычный in("41","42","43"). А то, что можно заказать несколько размеров никаким образом к фильтру отношения не имеет. На я.маркете тоже есть фильтр, но и там нельзя выбрать товары которые бывают **одновременно** 5 цветов или 3 размеров.

Comment: Если что-то где-то (да пусть и нигде) не реализовано - это не повод не реализовать. Впрочем. это уже головняк автора, пусть думает, надо оно ему или как.